# Сделать метод в JS

Tags: javascript

Помогите с решением задачи. Нужно создать метод который принимает флаг ascendingSort типа `boolean`, внутри метода создать список типа `Int` длинной 10 элементов, заполнить список рандомными значениями. Затем нужно отсортировать список либо по возврастанию либо наоборот в зависимости от флага `ascendingSort`. Если `ascendingSort == true`, то по возврастанию, иначе по убыванию.

Comment: Что у вас конкретно не получается? Вопросы в чём заключаются? Разбейте задачу на десяток мелких и по ступеням решайте

Comment: А рандомные числа, вам какой диапазон?

Answer (score 4):

```js
let s=(f=false)=>[...Array(10)].map(e=>Math.random()*99|0).sort((a, b)=>f?a-b:b-a);

console.log(s(true).toString());
console.log(s(false).toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот ваш готовый код.

```js
function sortList(ascendingSort) {
    let list = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1 + 1)) + 1);
    }
    list.sort(function(a, b) {
        return ascendingSort == true ? a - b : b - a;
    });
    return list;
}

console.log(sortList(true).toString());
console.log(sortList(false).toString());
```